# how to read data from database on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
def add
    if params[:note_add] == "Add"
      Note.create({:user_id => @user["id"], :note_type => params[:type], :text => params[:note_text], :lng => params[:lng], :lat => params[:lat]})
    end
  end
```

I am new on Ruby on Rails and I am trying to get data from database. How could i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a relation DB like MySQL, Postgres or other you should use Active Record that RoR brings. It's a ORM and provides plenty of functionalities for interacting with DB, and it seems your are already using it. For querying data check this page on the guides.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Some examples

```
Note.find(1) #get note with id=1
Note.find_by_note_type("sometype") #gets first found with note_type="sometype" (I think so)
Note.where("note_type = ?", "sometype") #gets all notes that have note_type="sometype"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this... 
You can look at https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-216 it is source of http://railscasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3 rails cast.
There you can see how easily generate CRUD operations with your data with scaffold. It will help you to understand main idea of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

`Note.find()` or `Note.all`

Assuming you've already created the `Note` model. Try it out in the console `rails console`